# Database table in which WTPart or Change activity Maturity History is stored

Tags: ptc-windchill

I need to pull the date on which a WTPart was in inwork state or A CN was in published state.
I did my analysis and found that there should be a Maturity history table in database, but i ended up with a table called MaturityBaseline table which does not hold this information. I need guidance on which table this information is stored. Even in API com.ptc.windchill.enterprise.history.HistoryTablesCommands.maturityHistory(wtObject); they are using Maturity History class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method from same class?

```
com.ptc.windchill.enterprise.history.HistoryTablesCommands.getLegacyLifeCycleHistory(LifeCycleManaged arg0);
```

I have never tried by myself though. Also check for `HistoryRecord` table in database whether it have any info related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is may years old now, but I stumbled across it looking at how to find the history of a change issue/problem report.

My problem report has a number TA00025 and I want to find when it was completed. The enter_phase action will tell me whenever the state has changed. This SQL will tell me changes of state for the nominated change issue/problem report (the same object type in Windchill)

```
select LH.action, LH.state, LH.updateStampA2
from wcadmin.[wcadmin].ObjectHistory OH,  wcadmin.[wcadmin].LifeCycleHistory LH,
wcadmin.wcadmin.WTChangeIssueMaster CIM, wcadmin.wcadmin.WTChangeIssue CI
where OH.idA3A5 = CI.idA2A2
and OH.idA3B5 = LH.idA2A2
and CI.idA3masterReference = CIM.idA2A2
and CIM.WTCHGISSUENUMBER = 'TA00025'
and LH.action = 'Enter_Phase'
```

For a WTPart the history all sits in the table WTPart which will have a full history for a part wth multiple records.